# NSSet filtered objects are removed from previous fetched object from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a one to many relationship setup in my Core Data:

```
Day <----->> Transactions
```

A day object will contain an `NSSet` of transactions and a `Date`.
At some point I want to fetch the latest Day and get its `Transactions` filtered by a period (monthly and yearly) and add them to another `Day` object and save this.

Here is my code:

```
// get latest day from core data
let lastDay = fetchDays(context: context) { request in
    request.sortDescriptors = Day.defaultSortDescriptors
    request.fetchLimit = 1
}.first
```

This will get me the correct Day object. After this I want to get the filtered transactions:

```
let filteredTransactions = lastDay?.transactions?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "period IN %@", [.monthly, .yearly]))
```

After I have the filtered transactions I want to add them to a new Day object and save that in Core Data:

```
context.performChanges {
   let day = Day(context: self.context)
   day.date = NSDate.today()
   day.transactions = filteredTransactions as NSSet?
}
```

This will also correctly save inside Core Data, but after this point, the transactions that I filtered out (monthly and yearly) have been removed from the `lastDay` object.

If I fetch that object again, the transactions are gone.
And I have no idea what is going on. It seems that any type of transactions that are filtered are also removed.

I tried all day long to figure out what is going on, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the relationship between Day and Transactions breaking the result? The lastDay relates with filtered transactions, but after you creates a new Day record, and change the ownership of filtered transactions to new record?

Comment: What can I do ? I try to create a mutable copy of the NSSet, still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a full new list of transactions and set the day object of each transaction to the new Day record:

```
context.performChanges {
    let day = Day(context: self.context)
    day.date = NSDate.today()
    if let transactions = filteredTransactions {
        for t in Array(transactions) {
            let transaction = Transactions(context: self.context)
            transaction.clone(from: t) // write extension method to Transactions
            transaction.day = day
        }
    }

}
```